# sabredav installation and xampp

Tags: php, windows-7, installation, xampp, sabredav

i want to install sabredav on my system but i can't;

my os is windows7 and i use xampp.
i download sabredav 1.7.9.zip. i create a folder on htdocs. the folder name is "my_project"
and i copy the zip file on the folder. 
i user php sample of sabredav :

include 'vendor/autoload.php';
echo 'SabreDAV ', \Sabre\DAV\Version::VERSION, ' is installed.';

but this error occurred:

SabreDAV
Fatal error: Class 'Sabre\DAV\Version' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\RataOs\r.php on line 4

please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the latest SabreDAV for that to work. SabreDAV switched to PHP 5.3 namespace in version 1.8.

Comment: how i must do it?
i must copy sabredav files into webdav folder of xampp?
do you have any totorial for install and use sabredav with xampp?
thanks